# E notation in C

Tags: c, scientific-notation

I'm reading *C Programming - A modern approach*, and I have stumbled across the section about E-notation. I have difficulties to understand them.

Take the following code:

```
printf("%12.5e", 30.253);
```

This results to the following output:

```
3.02530e+01
```

Can someone explain how this works? What does the number 12 signify here?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The `printf` `"%12.5e"` format instructs `printf` to convert the `double` (or `float`) argument to a string in exponential notation with 5 digits after the `.` and a total of at least 12 characters.  In your example, the output actually contains an extra space before the number: `3.02530e+01` to make for a total of `12` characters.  To make it more obvious, you can try:

```
printf("|%12.5e|\n", 30.253);
```

And verify that the output is:

```
| 3.02530e+01|
```

Exponential notation produced by `printf()` always uses a single digit before the `.` and an exponent (`e+01` here) representing the power of `10` by which to multiply the number.  It is a notation commonly used in the scientific community:

```
30.12 is the same as 3.012e1 or 3.012e+01
0.0012 is the same as 1.2e-3
```

You can use this syntax to write floating point constants in your `C` source code.

Comment: Thank you. But why Is the zero remove after the digit three, and placed after he the comma?

Comment: This is the very idea of the scientific notation. <digit>.<digits> * 10^<exponent>.

Answer (score 3):

`"%12.5e"` means:

(The format is `%[flag][minimumFieldWidth][.precision]conversionSpecifier`)

- `12`: [minimumFieldWidth] result should occupy 12 characters (default right justification)
- `.5`:[.precision] result should have 5 decimal places
- `e`: [conversionSpecifier] result will be in exponential notation

You can try playing with the value and see for yourself how the output changes.

See: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Printf_format_string